# How to debug 'This webpage was reloaded because a prob-lem occurred' on Safari Desktop

Tags: angular, debugging, safari

I have a WebRTC application built using AngularJS. This is working as expected on all browsers except Safari (testing on 11). The page intermittently reloads because of a problem, even when not performing an action on the page. I can't reproduce it successfully but need to find out what is causing it.

I don't want to go down the route of dissecting and removing code to pinpoint it if I don't have to.

Is there a way in Safari to log to a file so I can identify the crash? Inspector tools are no help for this.

Thanks